# Spark: load csv file with a different schema

Tags: apache-spark

I have a csv file like this :

```
product price,product origin,phone number
20,US,200200
```

I would like to load the csv file using a new schema so that my dataset should look like this:

```
|price | origin | number |
|20    | US     | 200200 |
```

I tried to create a schema using `structfield` :

```
sparkSession.read().format("csv")
                .option("header", "false")
                .option("delimiter", ",")
                .schema(myScheme).load(csv)
```

but what I got is like this:

```
|price     | origin | number |
|200200    | US     | 20     |
```

What is the correct way to load the csv with a new scheme with correct column orders ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a csv file with the exact contents that you posted in your question:

```
product price,product origin,phone number
20,US,200200
```

You should be able to  create a schema by using types from `org.apache.spark.sql.types._`. You could do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val mySchema = new StructType()
  .add("product price", IntegerType)
  .add("product origin", StringType)
  .add("phone number", StringType)

val df = spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(mySchema)
  .csv("./simpleCSV.csv")

df.show
+-------------+--------------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|product price|product origin|phone number|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+-------------+--------------+------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|           20|            US|      200200|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+-------------+--------------+------------+

df.printSchema                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
root                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 |-- product price: integer (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 |-- product origin: string (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 |-- phone number: string (nullable = true)
```

Hope this helps!