# How to get the mode of a column from a dataframe using spark scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I'm trying to get the mode of a column in a dataframe using spark scala but my code is not working.

For example

```
val type_mode = dfairports.groupBy("type").count().orderBy("count").first()
print("Mode", type_mode.get(0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! You're probably getting the least common value now, since the `orderBy` function by default orders by ascending values. So taking the first element will take the lowest value.

Try:

```
val type_mode = dfairports.groupBy("type").count().orderBy(desc("count")).first()
print("Mode", type_mode.get(0))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't know why spark loads the dataset with all columns as string

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71350057/spark-load-csv-file-with-a-different-schema) helps you there? If you can't find anything on Stackoverflow that answers your question, just make a new one!